# Is there a way to completely delete a previously deleted file without formatting the whole drive?

Tags: hard-disk, deleted-files

I am working on a server with others and I want to completely delete files which were previously deleted using 'rm'. I cannot format the server disk as others share it with me. Is it effective to shred the parent location where I used to store the files.

Comment: I believe srm can safely erase free space.  Might take a while, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the future, you would do better to overwrite or shred the file
contents before removing the file.

On a personal machine, you could overwrite free space by copying /dev/zero to new files until the hard disk is full, then deleting
those files, perhaps with some difficulty after booting from
a different device, or in single-user mode.

On a shared server, filling the disk might affect the other users, and dealing with the aftermath might be more awkward.

Also, "filling the disk" completely might not be truly possible
for an un-privileged user since an ext{2,3,4} file system 
usually reserves some free space for the root/admin user, 
and SSD drives may not erase some parts of hardware.

Google "shred" and "overwrite" and perhaps "forensic 
countermeasures" for many endless discussions on how 
to securely erase files - for most purposes, overwriting
once is enough, but some people view physical shredding
followed by incineration as insufficiently cautious.

```
Is it effective to shred the parent location where I used to store the files.
```

If you mean the parent directory, you could move any other files
to a different directory, then remove the old parent directory.

Comment: Note that `shred` and similar tools will only overwrite the latest copy of the file. If the file has been copied around, there may still be traces left on disk.

Comment: Note that "overwriting a file" means different things to different people, especially on a SSD.